# "Time settles everything"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is this a common phrase? A google search found only 6 pages using this exact phrase. What do you think of this phrase?

What about "time solves everything?"

Comment: If this were physics.stackexchange.com...

Comment: Asking if something is common or popular may not be entirely on-topic for this site.

Comment: Maybe I should delete this post then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so common that I've ever heard it before, but on the other hand its meaning seems clear enough; I certainly wouldn't be shy about using it if the situation seemed to call for it.

Answer (score 4):

"Time heals everything" - or originally "Time heals all wounds" (chaucer) is probably more common